# Date range picker clear date error, How can i un select the date once it get selected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker

I'm currently using a custom date range selection component in my application. When a user clicks on a date, it doesn't get unselected automatically, so I've added an "X" button for clearing the date, and that works as expected.

However, in my async request, the date is sent as "mm/dd/yy,mm/dd/yy," leading to errors. To mitigate this, I've added a condition to set the date to an empty string if it matches this format:

javascript
`if (date === "mm/dd/yy,mm/dd/yy") { date = ""; }`

Comment: can you address the root cause of the problem, which is that the date is being sent in the incorrect format in your async request?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.